# Prevent Webpack from modifying javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

I have webpack in my plain HTML, CSS, and Javascript application. I use webpack to convert scss to CSS. I want my javascript to be the same untouched in my dist folder, as I want to edit it later my wordpress projects. Webpack is adding a lot of code, which makes the JS files hard to edit later. Here is my config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin = require("html-webpack-partials-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    index: "./src/js/index.js",
    about: "./src/js/about.js",
    courses: "./src/js/courses.js",
    contactUs: "./src/js/contact-us.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    assetModuleFilename: "images/[name][ext]",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: { directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist") },
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].css",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Leads",
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./src/pages/index.html",
      chunks: ["index"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Leads About",
      filename: "about-us.html",
      template: "./src/pages/about-us.html",
      chunks: ["about"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Courses",
      filename: "courses.html",
      template: "./src/pages/courses.html",
      chunks: ["courses"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Contact Us",
      filename: "contact-us.html",
      template: "./src/pages/contact-us.html",
      chunks: ["contactUs"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin({
      path: path.join(__dirname, "./src/partials/footer.html"),
      location: "partialfooter",
      template_filename: [
        "index.html",
        "about-us.html",
        "courses.html",
        "contact-us.html",
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin({
      path: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "./src/partials/components/infrastructure.html"
      ),
      location: "infrastructure",
      template_filename: [
        "index.html",
        "about-us.html",
        "courses.html",
        "contact-us.html",
      ],
    }),
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: "/node_modules",
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          //   "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

How can I get webpack to convert my sass files, but simply copy my JS files?

Comment: Use `raw-loader` instead of `babel-loader`

Comment: When I use raw loader, I still see webpack javascript code in my javascript files. I want the javascript files to be intact actually

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `copy-webpack-plugin` https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ to copy files from your src static folder to your build destination folder. Roughly like this -

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
        { from: "source", to: "dest" },
        { from: "other", to: "public" },
    ],
    }),
],
};
```

The code that Webpack adds can allow many features for JavaScript like transpiling ES6 JavaScript to ES5, bundling, code-splitting and dynamic imports. But if you don't need them a straight copy might do.